# I have created a website with client side and server side Contents and actions in server side are working.But It is not available in client side

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I have created a website with client side and server side Contents and actions in server side are working.But It is not available in client side

here is my **c#  code**

```
 public void getBanner()
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "GetBanner_Home";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        DataTable dtb = dboMrk.GetDataTableFrmDB(cmd);
        if (dtb.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            rptBanner.DataSource = dtb;
            rptBanner.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

here is **stored procedure**

```
    CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetBanner_Home]
As
select banner_Image from Home_banner where banner_Status='A' order by banner_Id Desc
```

here is **design part**

```
    <div id="wrapper">


     <!-- Slideshow 4 -->
    <div class="callbacks_container">

      <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">

        <li>

              <asp:Repeater ID="rptBanner" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>  
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">  
         <img  src='<%#"banner/" + Eval("banner_Image")%>' class="img-responsive" ></img></li>
                </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

        </li>


      </ul>

    </div>


 </div>
```

Comment: What kind of error this will give?

Comment: You are showing images in the page? what is the path of 'banner_Image' - @Anu

Comment: The banner is not displaying in client side-@Divyesh Gausvami

Comment: I have created a folder name  banner. Images will stored in that folder and also in database table. I want to  take image from that folder.@Rajan

Comment: Did you bind banner_Image value? I don't see it.